# Mat data structures in OpenCV for android - looking for good explanation

Tags: java, android, opencv, data-structures, type-conversion

I think that more pepole have similar problem like me: Recently I am working on computer vision project on android. I am using OpenCV libraries, which have some strange for me data types (I have never see them before). Those types include:

- Mat
- MatOfInt
- MatOfPoint
- MatOfPoint2
- MatOfPoint4 etc.

I was trying to read documentation but there is nothing written about those data types or I didn't find it.

I am also interested in conversion between those data types, because poor OpenCV for android uses in different methods same date but in different types...

**Could someone explain mentioned OpenCV data structures for me? The best explanation would be graphical explanation, if possible.**

Answer (score 0):

You can see the OpenCV description of what a image Mat is [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) which explains, and shows graphically what a Mat is. It is how I learnt and it makes sense.

Basically a Mat is a matrix of information, in a 2x2, 3x3.. nxn, if you don't know what matrices are then google it there will be lots of simple explanations. e.g.

```
    1 1 1
    1 1 1
    1 1 1
```

would be a 3x3 matrix full of ones, this is also a matrix that shows a black square (I think)

therefore, a MatofX is simply a matrix containing data of that particular type, i'm not sure about actual conversions in OpenCV though.

Conversion types to C++ data types are [Here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aRH2jnsE5OoQJ%3aanswers.opencv.org/question/11021/confusion-between-opencv4android-and-c-data-types/&hl=en&gl=uk&strip=1)

also read here about [Conversion](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9DFxfsu0rnAJ%3aanswers.opencv.org/question/6206/opencv4android-conversion-from-matofkeypoint-to/&hl=en&gl=uk&strip=1)

Comment: Just the Mat type is basic, but for example convexity defects are saved in MatOfInt4. What does 4 stands for? And what would be graphical representation of that? And way to traverse it?

Comment: Int4 is a 4 byte integer (Long int) - I have edited my answer to include more information